# Regarding zooming images in SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, images

I tried clicking on an image (high width, low height) and this is how it showed up:

[image: image with zoom buttons]

And it's actually zoomed in, inside that box. So rest of the image, except the part in that box, is invisible.

Right now, I have to try and stay within that box and pan/zoom within it, which is hard for an image like this. And those huge zoom buttons don't really work for cases like this, as they themselves take up half the space in the box.

Can we just zoom it using the whole screen, like it's done in the Gallery app? That way even moving around the image would be easier.